# Water seeping in from trim around door at bottom of concrete casement stairs outside

Tags: basement, stairs

I have an outdoor basement entrance that is below level. When it’s raining I am getting water coming up from between the stairs and the cement foundation. The lower the stairs the more the water spurts out.

At the very bottom, water is coming out of the trim that is on the cement stair pad.

Usually do not have this issue unless it’s raining but if I just silicon the sides of the stairs will it just push the water level higher?

Photo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jro3nvYMBOhVb1zrwqHjoARkuhZG-DkE/view?usp=drivesdk

Here is a video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/106c-6C-mz8H_gte3p9Vn06IFPc25T-QO/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: It says I need access, when I try to look at the photos.  Please edit the question and add them here.  You may need to resize them first.

Comment: You probably need to fix drainage problems around your house.  Either regrading, or addition of french drains or similar.  Do you have gutters and downspouts?  Where does the water go when it comes between the stairs?

Comment: I changed access on the drive links. The water will normally just fall down the steps into the drain on the 36x36 pad at the base of the stairs. That’s working fine with any water that comes up. I believe the water is getting under the stairs and just pushing up through any cracks it can find at the lowest point which is at the basement cement wall and the bottom step next to the wooden trim. I was thinking using hydraulic cement to fill in all the cracks. The water itself is normal run off from around the yard. It’s sloped all around so not too worried about it.  House side is piped away.